# how to solve password command failed Error While sending mail in php

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

can someone help me to find what is wrong with the following code because when i try to send mail in php i am getting the following error

```
2015-01-05 09:18:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2015-01-05 09:18:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2015-01-05 09:18:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: cGV0ZXJwcm9ncmFtZXIxOTkxQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==  
2015-01-05 09:18:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWFuaTE5OTE= 
2015-01-05 09:18:21 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 xq4sm53656187pbb.21 - gsmtp 
2015-01-05 09:18:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2015-01-05 09:18:21 SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

code..

```
<?php
require "PHPMailerAutoload.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Mailer="smtp";
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'peter1991@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->From = 'peter1991@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'peter';
$mail->AddAddress('manikandan@gmail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('john1991@gmail.com', 'John');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via Sendmail, basic";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->Body    = "Hello";
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

if my guess is right there must be some credential problem with gmail but i am totally confused i am in the middle of my college proj i cannot move further without solving this.
any help is welcome thanks in advance

Comment: i have tried all the examples in the internet but no ex helps me to solve this problem.

Comment: I guess you tried all the examples except the one that matters - [the one that's bundled with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Answer (score 0):

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';`

have a try

Comment: Don't use ssl on 465; use tls on 587.

Comment: @Synchro explain please, why?

Comment: Because it's been [deprecated since 1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS)! It was an RFC recommendation for less than a year! PHP doesn't suffer from being written by Microsoft so doesn't need to use an obsolete standard. SSL on 465 does still work on gmail (because gmail does have to cater for broken clients), but there's no good reason to use it, so it's a good habit to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->Username = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "test";
```

Comment: Don't use ssl on 465; use tls on 587.